# Ejecutable jar de java, no carga archivos del proyecto

Tags: java, archivo, filewriter

Tengo un proyecto en java, en el cual abro un archivo pdf mediante una opción,cuando lo corro desde IntelliJ, me carga el archivo sin problemas, pero al momento de crear el .jar no lo carga y me dice que no existe el archivo. El código es el siguiente:

```
if (e.getSource() == menuLenguaje){
        try {
            File path = new File(getClass().getResource("/Archivos/lenguaje.pdf").getFile());
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Ya se aque lo ponga en una carpeta(paquete) llamada Archivos o lo mande llamar desde la ubicación en src no me carga el archivo.

Comment: ¿Usas Spring? ¿usas maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo unas pruebas acá, me ha funcionado creando un archivo temporal de un PDF, es decir, copiándolo y usando `getResourceAsStream()` de la siguiente manera:

```
try {
  Path temp = Files.createTempFile( "temporal", ".pdf" );
  temp.toFile().deleteOnExit();

  // Sin backslash por delante en la ruta del recurso...
  InputStream IS = MiClase.class.getResourceAsStream( "Archivos/lenguaje.pdf" );
  Files.copy( IS, temp, StandardCopyOptions.REPLACE_EXISTING );
  Desktop.getDesktop().open( temp.toFile() );
} catch( Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Trabajó perfectamente tanto desde mi entorno de desarrollo como desde el JAR dispuesto a distribución.

### **Edito:**

Algo no menor; si de algún modo uno se pregunta en que directorio quedaría dicho archivo temporal si no se borra con el `deleteOnExit()`, con un simple
`System.out.println(temp)` se ve la ruta entera.

Comment: He probado tu solución y me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias Johny.